# Getting PHP Fatal error: Class 'IntlDateFormatter' not found

Tags: magento2, php, date, phpunit

When I execute the phpunit cases for one of the model, I'm getting the error below,

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'IntlDateFormatter' not found in /Users/userone/Sites/Magento-CE/vendor/phpunit/phpunit-mock-objects/src/Generator.php on line 1113
```

This is throwing an error even **intl module** is installed and `extension=php_intl.dll` is enabled in php.ini file.

When using **\Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\TimezoneInterface** as constructor argument I'm getting this issue.

How can I fix this error? Thanks in advance...

Comment: It seems that your PHP version and the intl extension version are not compatible. Please verify.

Comment: It looks like the PHP version 7.1.29 is compatible with PHPUnit 6.2.4. Any other idea on this?

Comment: Please check the link https://phpunit.de/supported-versions.html for compatibility of phpunit with PHP 7.1.

Comment: I cross verified with the given link of php and phpunit version. It looks correct. I also checked the composer.json file where we have configured the phpunit version. Is there any other way to inject \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\TimezoneInterface with another?